# Prevent Window from Becoming Visible or Open it Off-screen?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I have a script in which I click a button that opens a new window. I'd like to do some stuff in that window, and then close it again, returning control to the original active window. Ideally, I want to do this without the user seeing the window pop open at all.

Right now, I have my script move the window offscreen immediately after I click the button to open it, but you can still see the window opening for a split-second before WinMove kicks in.

```
MouseClick, Left, %buttonX%, %buttonY%
WinWait, Pop Up Win Title,, 1
WinMove, 9000, 9000
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to pre-emptively make the window invisible before I open it, or to otherwise make it so the appearance of the window is not noticeable. I've also tried the code above without WinWait, but it didn't make a difference.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you open this "window" with the `run` command? have you considered `run, ...,, Hide` and maybe `winshow, ...` later on?

Comment: In addition to Blauhirn's point, what is the window you're trying to manipulate. Is it something built into Windows that I (we) could try ourselves?

Comment: It's an custom program that I can't distribute. I'll add a code sample above that shows how I'm opening it. It's not with any run or winshow commands, it's opened by the parent process when I click a button.